# Why is $x$ not always equal to $vt$ in Lorentz transformation $t^{\prime}=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$?

Tags: relativity

Distance is the product of speed and time; so distance must be $x=vt$ but I realized $x$ can be non-zero even if $t=0$ . What does this mean? And under which circumstances $x$ is equal to $v$t and $x$ is NOT equal to $vt$?

Comment: If your walk from home to work takes you past a streetlamp, is there ever a time when you are not directly under the streetlamp?

Comment: $x = x_0 + \int v\cdot dt$. No need for x=0 at t=0, and no need for $v$ to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Only the origin of the primed coordinate system has an unprimed coordinate $x=vt$. The object under study may not be at $x = 0$ or $x' = 0$ when $t = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to pay attention to what a Lorentz transformation is, and what the symbols refer to.

Consider two frames of reference, $S$ and $S'$.  The $S'$ frame is moving with velocity $v$ with respect to the $S$ frame, and their origins coincide when $t=0$.

If an observer in frame $S$ sees an event occur at location $x$ and time $t$, then an observer in frame $S'$ will see that same event occur at location $x'$ and time $t'$.  The Lorentz transformation tells us how to relate those two observations:

$$ x' = \gamma\left(x - vt\right)$$
$$ t' = \gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right) $$

Your question is

> Why does the location $x$, at which one of the observers sees an event, not always equal the velocity $v$ of some different, arbitrary reference frame multiplied by the time $t$ at which the observer sees the event occur?

Hopefully the answer to that is clear - it's because none of those variables has anything *whatsoever* to do with the others.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not be discouraged by how abrasive this site can sometimes be. It is very easy to have the confusion that you are having. I also had it, when I was learning these things.

In English, we'd say that the distinction you're having trouble with, is the difference between a *space* and a *trajectory*.

So if I am walking down the street from one building to another, I am following a *trajectory*. You might measure how far I get from one to the other, as a function of how long I have been walking. Then of course if I walk at a constant velocity $v$, my distance $x$ and the time elapsed $t$ follow the equation $x = v~t.$

But now imagine that we make little marks on the street, to tell me when I have passed 100m, 200m, 300m, and so forth -- you might see these marks in a marathon or another race, for example. Well now we start thinking about a more abstract idea. This idea is that the points on the street have their own positions $x$ which have nothing to do with me and my trajectory. These marks help you to think of a *space,* where each point in the space has different *coordinates*. (Please be careful if you need to translate this word "space". It is used in English to mean both "the places above the Earth's atmosphere," as in "outer space", but also to mean a very plain region that does not have any remarkable features on its own, as in "a wide-open space." I am only talking about the second of these.)

Now before you get to relativity, you will have to think about two different descriptions of a space, that are moving relative to each other. The easiest way to think about this, is to think about a train.

If we make marks on the ground, we have one description of the coordinates on a moving train. But if we make marks on the floor of the train, we have a different description. If at some time we pretend is $t=0,$ those marks perfectly line up, and the train moves in the $x$ direction with velocity $v$, then a point is marked with both the train's coordinates $x'$ and with the ground coordinates $x$, but you can convert between them if you know how long the train has been moving for, so if you know the time $t$. In other words an *event* -- a point in space and time -- corresponds to two coordinates $(t, x)$ according to the ground and $(t', x')$ according to the train, and they obey the relation, $$\begin{align}x' &= x - v t\\t' &= t.\end{align}$$ That second equation might seem very obvious to you, that first equation might not seem so obvious. It says that something which moves along with the train, and has position $x_0 + v~t$ according to the ground, stays at the same coordinate $x_0$ as described in the train. But notice that these $x$ and $t$ and $x'$ and $t'$ numbers are describing all of the points of the space: clouds above the train, people inside the train, people outside the train, and so on. Someone inside the train does not feel that they are moving, not if the train is very smooth and not speeding up or slowing down. You can juggle just fine in a moving train. But if you open the window you will think that there is a breeze blowing past you at velocity $-v,$ because the air is at a constant location with respect to the ground but in the train's coordinates it is moving with velocity $-v.$

Now once you really understand all of that, you can understand our language of relativity. Let us just focus on velocity changes much less than the speed of light. There is a very slight modification to the above two equations, it is that time coordinates are also changing. This means, we need to think about our little marks, and put a little clock on each one. Those little clocks are ticking in-sync with each other. So someone on the ground will think that all of the clocks on the ground hit 0 at the same time, then they all hit 1 at the same time exactly one second later, then they all hit 2 at the same time exactly one second after that.

Here's the weird thing about relativity: if this train moves fast enough, then the people on the train will look down at the clocks on the ground, and they will *not* think that they are all in-sync. For small velocities we have the same $x' = x - v~t$ equation but in relativity we understand $t'=t-v~x/c^2,$ where $c$ is the speed of light. This means that all of these clocks are still striking "1" at $t=1\text{ s}$ but this happens at different $t'$ in the coordinates of the train. For things that are further forward, this happened at earlier $t',$ and for things that are further behind, this happens at later $t'.$ It is a very small effect because you divide by $c^2$ and $c$ is a very large number. But if you looked very closely from within the train, you would see that the clocks ahead of you all seem to have "sped up" a little bit when the train left the station and accelerated to $+v$, so they all seem to be "ahead" of all of the clocks behind you which seem to have "slowed down" when you accelerated.

For small $v$ they seem to all be ticking at the same rate but as you go faster and faster, more and more do these tiny little effects mix with each other. They finally combine into a prefactor, $x' = (x - v~t)/\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}$ and $t' = (t - v~x/c^2)/\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2},$ which means that the clocks you are passing start seem to be ticking slower and slower in the train's coordinates, and also the marks on the ground seem to be closer together than 100 meters apart. Even more weird, all of the things you see from the outside world seem very distorted: the easiest way to understand this is if you imagine being in a spaceship going near the speed of light: as you accelerate, it will seem like all of the distant stars are crowding together into a point ahead of you. It is a very strange theory, when you let these little time-changes mix with these space-changes. (But, I want to be very clear about this, it is *strange* but it is *mathematically 100% consistent*. There are no true paradoxes here, the math all works out perfectly fine. Furthermore it is *absolutely a key part of our world* that these things happen, it has transitioned out of the "we think that's what's happening but we're not sure" phase of our knowledge into a phase of "we build things which wouldn't work if this wasn't happening, spending tons of money on these things, sure that these things will work. And they do.")

Answer (score 0):

I see you are interested in Lorentz transformations, relativity, but haven't studied anything on the topic. Don't worry, just read more, you will get these answers.
Just a quick heads up, there is another lorentz transformation equation:
$x'=\gamma\left( x- vt\right)$.

And the x you use here is not the displacement but the position of the body, while v is the velocity of the frame.